# A good algorithm to divide payments among ALL developers of a Github repo based on statistics

Tags: git, algorithm, project-management

Recently someone on r/bitcoin started using our crowd-payment system to directly reward the Bitcoin core developers. Our system divides payments based on participation levels. A kind of one-to-many payment.

This resulted in quite a [discussion](http://www.reddit.com/r/Bitcoin/comments/3240ro/im_now_funding_all_the_devs_in_the_world_who_are/) (but also in $600 of donations and 20-25 of the core developers quickly signing up to [collect their rewards](https://mobbr.com/#/task/aHR0cHM6Ly9naXRodWIuY29tL2JpdGNvaW4vYml0Y29pbg==/persons)). One of the main arguments was that it is impossible to reward developers based on simple statistics such as LOC.

We only partly agree, and one of their lead developers Gavin Andreesen said our algorithm did [quite well](http://www.reddit.com/r/Bitcoin/comments/3240ro/im_now_funding_all_the_devs_in_the_world_who_are/cq82k0l).

**My question is, if you had to divide rewards among all contributors to a Github repo, based on the repo's [Github statistics](https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/graphs/contributors), what algorithm/calculation would YOU suggest.**

On Github only a few types of participation are measured/rated. In that regard it is not a very social platform (yet). Instead of just using LOC, our algorithm weighs:

- the number of commits accepted into main branch
- number of lines added
- number of lines deleted
- recentness of a contribution
- It does some normalisation to reduce extremes

Also remember that repos are moderated by means of pull-request. So there is quality control before the algorithm does its thing.

*To demonstrate the concept, **we pledged EUR100 to this question**. When an answer is accepted, it will be divided among ALL answers based on votings. Rewards can be collected by OAUTH-ing your stackoverflow account.*

https://mobbr.com/#/task/aHR0cHM6Ly9zdGFja292ZXJmbG93LmNvbS9xdWVzdGlvbnMvMjk2MDY3NTgvYS1nb29kLWFsZ29yaXRobS10by1kaXZpZGUtcGF5bWVudHMtYW1vbmctYWxsLWRldmVsb3BlcnMtb2YtYS1naXRodWItcmVwby1iYXNlZA==

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about programming as defined in the [help].  This is a business question.

Comment: And I'm flagging it as off-topic because it's *primarily opinion based*.

Answer (score 6):

You don't ship code, you ship features. (well actually, maybe you don't ship anything, but still, you care about your code doing stuff, not just sitting there)

IMO the only reasonable way to spend grants for open-source projects is a bounty-based system.

For one thing, you get to spend the money you have now for future devs.

Secondly, you can involves the community much more directly, by letting them pledge to a specific bounty (for a feature or a bug) OR NOT.

Lastly some driving entity gets to prioritize the work by putting higher bounties or higher priority or more difficult tasks.

PS: "But We don't have such an entity". Then you are pirates. Take the money and run.

EDIT:

I understand that you would want to reward people for the work they have already done. It might be that this is felt as needed by your community, and I wouldn't pretend to know the politics involved.

However to a larger point, I think you are trying to solve with an algorithm ,a posteriori, some problem that should be solve by a steering committee and the community, a priori.

All the money that you have that isn't pledge directly at a specific feature or bug-related issue, you can use to fund refactoring and plumbing work (which tend to be underfunded by users via the bounty system).

It is never too late to put in place such a system and consider that the money pledged so far was pledge to the project in general and should be re-allocated within the project by the aforementioned steering committee.

Comment: This is possible in Mobbr. If you pay to an issue or milestone that is still open, it is a crowdfunding. But as soon as the issue or milestone is closed, the rewards will still have to be divided using some kind of algorithm.

Comment: @PatrickSavalle I don't understand. If I pledge for issue A $10, guy who fixes issue A gets $10. done. If I pledge $50 for the project it means :"You guys know what to do with it, use it to place whatever bounties on whatever issues you have, or buy a server I don't care"

Comment: Maybe, but paying for an existing, ongoing collaboration incentivises other to join! And it is probably much fairer than a 'normal' reward system.

Comment: @PatrickSavalle I added an edit. I understand that you might want to reward the past work. However keep in mind people did this work without any promise, and it would probably be more encouraging to see the future of the project funded rather that receiving 50$ for 2 years of involvment.

Answer (score 5):

My theory: Every measurement that can be determined solely by a program (e.g. # of lines of code added or deleted) is vulnerable to *trivial* gaming.  Every other measurement by definition relies partly on human input (e.g. # commits accepted into main branch) and is vulnerable to the usual "social" problems like corruption and favouritism -- but these are still *infinitely* better than the first kind.  Automatic measurements should only ever be used as "lower bound rules", like "Hasn't even visited the site in the last year ==> Not eligible for anything."

Comment: Partly agree. Github should have more mechanisms (such as voting). But rewarding social collaboration this way,is not only about fair reward, it is also about incentivising other to join, being able to steer a crowd and offer a way to earn a living by 'just going online and add value'. We have to start somewhere.

Comment: I didn't mean to criticise your effort -- I think it's great, and as I said I think that measurements involving human input (like # accepted commits) can work.

Comment: As a separate idea to incentivise newcomers, you might try having your (human-involving) measurements merely "push" some baseline "All n developers get 1/n of the cash" distribution function in the "direction" of favouring the contributors who measure higher.  (I'm thinking of how (good) product rating systems on websites use false counts to avoid massive variance in ratings in the early stages when there are just a few ratings.)  This does create the possibility for gaming, but in the end it's a tradeoff, and this way you can at least make it explicit and tweak the parameters yourself :)

Answer (score 3):

Just a very simple idea :

Divide the money equally among all the developers who contributed during the last month.

It may help keeping some of the developers involved in the project, whilst preventing for them quarreling about money since everybody will get the same amount.

Money was not the reason they started contributing anyway. It shouldn't be and it's probably not their primary motivation as the money from donation will probably never represent enough to pay for the real value of the features they developped.

Answer (score 3):

I'd say that the best indicator of an user's participation's quality is **the number of commits accepted into main branch**. 
I mean, if you rewarded people that added more lines, you'd get some programmers repeating code and adding irrelevant or redundant lines just to get a better share. Deleting lines isn't quite the best way to identify users that improved your code's quality, in my opinion. Finally, recentness of a contribution doesn't define its quality and would incentivize programmers to deliver their work as late as possible... 
Hope that helped!

Answer (score 2):

The ones who say it wouldn't be fair to reward developers based on simple statistics are the ones who don't influence the statistics enough. I guess it's as simple as that.

I really like the Mobbr-system. He who had a influential participation gets what he worked for. There can be only many!

Answer (score 1):

There is a startup named [SourceCred](https://sourcecred.io/) which specializes in solving the exact same problem.